# App Center unable to install IOS release on iPhone 13

Tags: ios, react-native, mobile-development, visual-studio-app-center

I'm occuring an issue with App Center and Iphone 13 (IOS 17.2.1). I've already joined my organization and added my device in App center with the UDID.

When I click on the app to test, I can see this message : "The developers are working on a version for your device"

I also got access to the android version but can't figure out what's the issue on IOS.

However, I've added the App Center profile on each devices, and the iPhone 13 appears in my registered devices.

Did the process two times but still having this issue.

Does anyone already seen this and have the answer?

Comment: It sounds like you haven't updated the provisioning profile that app center is using to one with your device udid

Comment: Click this link to find the answer to your question. 
https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/issues/866